# jQuery get text value with br tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
<div class="mydiv"> 
    <p> Lorem ipsum <br/>Lorem ipsum <br/> Lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="otherDiv"> </div> 
</div>
```

I would like to get the text from the div **'mydiv'** but together with the **br** tags. I tried with `$('.mydiv).text()` but it removes **br** tags. Also tried with `.html()` but it shows all html in 'mydiv' but I want only to text with br tags.

Thanks for help.

Comment: If by 'with the `br` tags' you mean you want the plain-text content but with new line characters preserved, then look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bnsskmqq/7/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.html()` method on the child `p` element.

```js
console.log($(".mydiv p").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv"> 
  <p> Lorem ipsum <br/>Lorem ipsum <br/> Lorem ipsum </p>
  <div class="otherDiv"> </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the contents of the text, just select them instead of the parent `div`:

```js
console.log($(".mydiv p").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv"> 
    <p> Lorem ipsum <br/>Lorem ipsum <br/> Lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="otherDiv"> </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted me and Scott Marcus: could you explain why?